# How to "save with encoding"

Tags: encoding, atom-editor

I have *csv* file in *UTF-8* and I want to save it in *Cyrillic (Windows 1251)* ... in **Atom** I found only - reopen with encoding `ctrl+shift+u`

In **Sublime Text 3** there is "File -> Save with Encoding" - is there any alternatives in **Atom** ?

Comment: I'm looking for this aswell..

Comment: Still (2 years later) listed as an open issue on the Atom repository: https://github.com/atom/encoding-selector/issues/7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another option, without using any plugin: cut all text from file, then switch to the target encoding (`Ctrl-Shift-U`) in an empty editor and paste the text back.

As seen in 
https://github.com/atom/encoding-selector/issues/7#issuecomment-274257654

Comment: Even simpler: Mark all (CTRL-A), copy (CTRL-C), switch encoding of file to target encoding (e.g. via encoding selector in status bar), paste (CTRL-V), done! -- No need for a second editor :)

Answer (score 4):

Recently there is a plugin written for this: [Convert-file-encoding](https://atom.io/packages/convert-file-encoding)

To use the plugin, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, type `Convert File Encoding` to search for the function and select the encoding you want the file convert into.

Comment: This is a 404 now.

Comment: @haykam I have replaced it with the similar one.